# Which URL to be used for app engine client in cloud computing?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, cloud

I am using cloud computing in my app for push notification. I have a problem in client auth token. I am using the following for authenticating client login token

```
public class AppEngineClient {
    private static final String TAG = "AppEngineClient";

    public static final String BASE_URL = " <Don't know which URL to use here>";
    public static final String AUTH_URL = BASE_URL + "/_ah/login";
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "ah";

    public final Context mContext;
    public final String mAccountName;

    public AppEngineClient(Context context, String accountName) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mAccountName = accountName;
    }

    public HttpResponse makeRequest(String urlPath, List<NameValuePair> params) throws Exception {
        HttpResponse res = makeRequestNoRetry(urlPath, params, false);
        if (res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 500) {
            res = makeRequestNoRetry(urlPath, params, true);
        }
        return res;
    }

    public HttpResponse makeRequestNoRetry(String urlPath, List<NameValuePair> params, boolean newToken)
            throws Exception {

        // Get auth token for account
        Account account = new Account(mAccountName, "com.google");
        String authToken = getAuthToken(mContext, account);
        if (authToken == null) throw new PendingAuthException(mAccountName);
        if (newToken) {  // invalidate the cached token
            AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(mContext);
            accountManager.invalidateAuthToken(account.type, authToken);
            authToken = getAuthToken(mContext, account);
        }

        // Get ACSID cookie
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String continueURL = BASE_URL;
        URI uri = new URI(AUTH_URL + "?continue=" +
                URLEncoder.encode(continueURL, "UTF-8") +
                "&auth=" + authToken);
        HttpGet method = new HttpGet(uri);
        final HttpParams getParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(getParams, false);  // continue is not used
        method.setParams(getParams);

        HttpResponse res = client.execute(method);
        Header[] headers = res.getHeaders("Set-Cookie");
        if (res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 302 ||
                headers.length == 0) {
            return res;
        }

        String ascidCookie = null;
        for (Header header: headers) {
            if (header.getValue().indexOf("ACSID=") >=0) {
                // let's parse it
                String value = header.getValue();
                String[] pairs = value.split(";");
                ascidCookie = pairs[0];
            }
        }

        // Make POST request
        uri = new URI(BASE_URL + urlPath);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity =
            new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8");
        post.setEntity(entity);
        post.setHeader("Cookie", ascidCookie);
        post.setHeader("X-Same-Domain", "1");  // XSRF
        res = client.execute(post);
        return res;
    }

    public String getAuthToken(Context context, Account account) {
        String authToken = null;
        AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
        try {
            AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future =
                    accountManager.getAuthToken (account, AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, false, null, null);
            Bundle bundle = future.getResult();
            authToken = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
            // User will be asked for "App Engine" permission.
            if (authToken == null) {
                // No auth token - will need to ask permission from user.
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.ctp.AUTH_PERMISSION");
                intent.putExtra("AccountManagerBundle", bundle);
                context.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return authToken;
    }

    public class PendingAuthException extends Exception {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public PendingAuthException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class I am using for user authentication through app engine client through Chrome to phone example of cloud computing but I don't understand while using this class which BASE_URL, I have to give in this class. Please, tell me which URL to use and what to be done on server side if URL is from server side.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If Anybody knows about it then plzzzz help me out of my problem

Comment: @CommonsWare : Hello Sir... You are always being great in all.Can you please help me in this problem of mine.

Comment: Flagging your question because it isn't getting much attention is not allowed.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5472819/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Comment: @  Will: But I have made flagging becoz I am not getting satisfactory reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  pattern for AppEngine base URLs is either

`http://<<appname>>.appspot.com` or `https://<<appname>>.appspot.com`

Comment: @bgporter:
Ok but from where we get this URL

Comment: ...from whoever developed the application running on AppEngine that you're trying to connect to.

Comment: @bgporter: you mean to say that it is the server URL to which it needs to connect

Comment: @bgporter: What does this server side URL must contain actually and is my code correct if I include the app server URL path.....

Comment: I don't know enough about the situation to say more than what I said above -- `BASE_URL` appears to need to be `http://<<appname>>.appspot.com` , whatever <<appname>> might be.

Comment: @Nikki Have you uploaded your app to App Engine? If so, you should know the app ID - and hence the URL to use.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: You mean to say After uploading the app to App Engine, the URL that I will get will be used here.... I doesn't need to do anything on my server for getting authentication of google account

Comment: @Nikki Yes, that's the URL you should use. I can't speak as to having to do anything else, as I'm not familiar with the code.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: Ok thanks...... Can you please tell me if this URL as uploaded from App Engine will let me get access and authenticate to login token....

Comment: @Nikki I don't know, because I'm not familiar with the app or with exactly what you're trying to achieve. Try it and see.